Does nx affected work with git submodules
I'ld like to know if nx affected works with git submodules.
I suspect it relies on git CLI to discover changes, and as such, if the changes happen in a submodule, I am not sure if the change discovery mechanism will be able to see through the submodules themselves, because these are in different git trees.
related question: Is it possible to use different apps as git submodules in a nx workspace?
